# Conversion from binary to byte[] in c#

Tags: c#, binary, byte

I have an attachment of a MIME file which is encoded in binary format.
That binary data from the file is stored in a string variable in my application. My task is to convert that string to byte[] so that i can pass this to a stream object to upload it in the Azure blob storage. I am using the below code. Code does not break but once the it gets uploaded to Azure blob and I try to download it shows file is corrupt.

attachmentContents is the string object which contains the binary data.

```
//# byteAttachmentData is the byte[] 

byteAttachmentData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachmentContents)
```

Sample of binary data(Not pasting the entire content)

```
PK     ! ̘Շʁ  ͇   [Content_Types].xml (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ԕ̪ðEѶيڨƄɢХhύ͇ӤΩ%ʃoّͤdċh>֤l،XFZUمʾfo
Ąi
ŬƷ7ęׁɈmB˲D9h쁐%ԞŗࠠNɯѠ~?
```

Comment: How did you convert a binary file into a string in the first place? Do you need to do that? It's very unusual.

Comment: You should not store binary data in a string but in a byte  array (or stream) in the first place, can you not do that?

Comment: "_which is encoded in binary format._" Using what encoding... I doubt it is encoded as UTF8 (that's a text encoding, not an encoding for binary data)... What exactly looks the **encoded** string like, before you are trying to decode it? I bet my grandmother's life that the string you have is Base64-encoded data; in which case you should use a Base64 decoder... (.NET has a a Base64 encoder/decoder; use the search function in the .NET API browser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7.1 to find it...)

Comment: @elgonzo I am feeling nervous for your grandmother, I'm not so sure it is Base64...

Comment: @DavidG, she will understand ;-)

Comment: Looks like gzip format

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, the binary "dump"(?) rather indicates it is or once was a ZIP file (note the "PK")

Comment: Likely a docx / xlsx file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats

Comment: @DavidG - Mime file is received from BizTalk receive port and the conversion is happening via a custom code which parses the mime file.. extracts the payloads and attachments. Each payload and attachment is stored in the Body property of the mime class which is of string type.

Comment: @elgonzo This is definitely not base64 as we are currently able to process the base64 attachments via the code : byteAttachmentData = Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentContents)

Comment: @elgonzo RIP your grandmother :(

Comment: @AlexK.I tried assigning it directly to the stream object. my code executes fine but once it gets uploaded to the azure blob storage and i try to download it, the file doesn't open and it says file is corrupt.

Comment: @DavidG, dang! I don't know how i should tell her the bad news... hiding from her sounds like a reasonable strategy... ;-)

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, well, using UTF-8 encoding there does not really look that meaningful, as all you get is the UTF-8 octets that encode Unicode code points, but _not_ the binary data the string is supposed to represent. As others already mentioned, you should start with determining _accurately_ of how _exactly_ the original binary data was turned into that string. From there you will either know how to convert that string back to the binary data; or whether that attempt to convert the original binary data into a string was ill-conceived and unsuitable to represent binary data as a string.